# looping through a specific column in excel using python to find data begin with a ending i a specifc char

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, tuples, openpyxl

I am trying to loop through an excel sheet, wanting to find the latitude of a country and this excel sheet contains major cities and countries and I want to isolate and print to console all the countries that are have an S in the latitude column.

I found success just finding major cities with S in there string but due to the data containing example 123.N, I am unable to get a result:

```
whitelist = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
for cellObj in rows:
    Lat = str(cellObj[6].value)
    result = ''.join(filter(whitelist.__contains__, Lat))
    if 'S' in result:
        print(cellObj[3].value)
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: im trying to findout how to loop through and find 123.N but am unable to due to it, im can currently only loop through and find strings like Nick, i want to be able to loop through and locate all the data entries that have mixed characters

Comment: This looks more like a regex issue. Let's ignore cells and stuff for the moment and concentrate on the strings. Please provide examples of what you're seeing and what you want to happen.

Comment: so im seeing 124.N, 123.S, 99.N, 11.S in a list and i want to loop through them to get all the ones with just the S in them

Comment: I suspect your filter function is failing you try something like `re.search(^\d[1-3]S$)`

Comment: thats alright mate i found the issue, thanks heaps anyway!!

Comment: Please provide the correction below you original code.